# How to speed up XSLT processing time

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm currently using an XSLT file to transfer an XML file (a lot of mark-up language) to another XML file (pure text). The processing time is too long.

I guess this is because I'm using an `for-each` inside another `for-each` like this:
[element&attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Byhaw.png)

```
<xsl:for-each select="/data/row">
  <xsl:variable name="ROW_">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(./preceding-sibling::*) + 1"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:for-each select='/Header/*[starts-with (text(), 'Car')] '>
    <xsl:variable name="COLUMN_">
      <xsl:value-of select="count(./preceding-sibling::*) + 1"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="/data/row[position()=$ROW_]/@*[position()=$COLUMN_]"/>
    <xsl:value-of select ="$Delimiter"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

So what can I do to improve the processing time?

Comment: My guess is it's because you're using `count(./preceding-sibling::*)` instead of `position()`. But without a [mcve] it's only a guess. Note also that performance is processor-specific.

Answer (score 9):

There are many inefficiencies in this code, and I'll start with the small ones.

**ONE**

```
  <xsl:variable name="ROW_">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(./preceding-sibling::*) + 1"/>
  </xsl:variable>
```

Never use an xsl:variable with a contained xsl:value-of unless you really want to create a temporary XML tree structure. It's much more efficient to write

```
<xsl:variable name="ROW_" select="count(./preceding-sibling::*) + 1"/>
```

Doing it your way, you're calculating an integer value (with count()), converting it to a string, converting the string to a text node, creating a document node, and appending the text node to the document node; and when you use the variable in the predicate `[position()=$ROW_]`, you're getting the string value of the document node by finding and concatenating all its text nodes, and converting the result to an integer. MUCH better to bind the variable to an integer in the first place!

**TWO**

```
<xsl:for-each select='/Header/*[starts-with (text(), 'Car')] '>
```

This appears within an outer xsl:for-each, so it's executed repeatedly, but the result of `/Header/*[starts-with (text(), 'Car')]` is the same each time, it doesn't depend on anything in the loop. A smart optimizer will move the expression out of the loop (this isn't trivial because it depends on recognizing that "/" is going to select the same root node each time, which is only true because the outer for-each selects a single-document node set). Rather than relying on the optimizer being that smart, bind the expression `/Header/*[starts-with (text(), 'Car')]` to a variable.

**THREE**

```
<xsl:value-of select="/data/row[position()=$ROW_]/@*[position()=$COLUMN_]"/>
```

This is probably the critical one: within a loop that processes all the rows, you have a loop that processes all the rows, so you've immediately got O(n^2) performance: double the input size, and the execution time goes up by a factor of four.

Again, a smart optimizer like the one in Saxon-EE will probably sort this out (the construct is like a join in SQL, and optimization of joins is a well-established art). But if you're using an open-source processor, chances are its optimizer isn't that smart, so you have to optimize it by hand, which isn't at all hard to do: it looks to me as if the row you are selecting will be the one that the outer for-each is currently processing.

**FOUR**

```
@*[position()=$COLUMN_]
```

You've got a problem here, and it's not a performance problem. You are relying on the attributes being delivered in a particular order (the same order as the corresponding HEADER elements), and that's unsafe. You simply can't rely on order of attributes, so you are going to have to find some other way of controlling the order of the output here.

Ignoring that problem, I think your code reduces to:

```
<xsl:variable name="headers" 
    select='/Header/*[starts-with (text(), 'Car')] '/>
<xsl:for-each select="/data/row">
  <xsl:variable name="thisRow" select="."/>
  <xsl:for-each select='$headers'>
    <xsl:variable name="COLUMN_" 
         select="count(./preceding-sibling::*) + 1"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$thisRow/@*[position()=$COLUMN_]"/>
    <xsl:value-of select ="$Delimiter"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

(What's the significance of the underscores at the end of a variable name? That kind of unnecessary obfuscation gets me really irritated...)